# chown select files only

Tags: sync, chown

I use the (excellant) unison to sync two file servers and I've just realised i've synced a number of files without using the switch in unison that maintains the file user ownership. these files now have a user of root (coz i have to run unison as root)

Can I chown to a specified user BUT only change the files that now have the owner root and do so recursively in the directory in question? Sure i can but not sure of the arguments to "find files with owner 0 and change them to owner xxxx".

THX for any help...

Answer (score 4):

Run `find /search/dir -user root` and check it lists the appropriate files.

**Automatically changing system files from root ownership will do bad things to your system, so make sure this only finds files you want to change.**

Then `sudo find /search/dir -user root -exec chown myuser {} \;` will change the ownership of those files.

Comment: THANKS for the warning. I appreciate this is a dangerous manoeuvre! It's critical this only happens in my specified folder (which is a sub directory of /home) so I will do the find first! THX again